# ruby on rails: how to change BG color of options in select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, select

I want to pull list of colors from model and put the color select list in the view.
Options have value as color code. I want to change the background color of options same as its value. Below are two ways I tried to do but it comes out that it changes color for whole select list but not for individual options with individual colors.

```
<p>
    <b>Background color</b><br />    
    collection_select(:setting, :bg_color, @colors, :code, :name, 
    options ={:prompt => "-Select a color"}, html_options = {:style => "background-color: #3f3"})
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>New Background color</b><br />
 select_tag("setting[bg_color]", "<option>-Select a color</option>" + 
  options_from_collection_for_select(@colors, :code, :name, html_options = {:style => "background-color: #3f3"})) 
  </p>
```

I want it to generate something similar to:

```
<option value='color_code' style='background-color: color_code'  >color_name</option>
```

this way, the colors in options are also visible to the users.

anyway we can customize the options?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rails helpers don't support html_options like that.  You can make your own helper method, though.

```
def options_with_colors(colors)
  colors.collect do |color, code| 
    "<option value='#{code}' style='background-color:#{code};'>#{color}</option> "
  end.join
end
```

Call like:

```
@colors = ["Red" => "#f00", "Blue" => "blue"]
select_tag("setting[bg_color]", options_with_colors(@colors))
```